# On a hybrid laptop, which will save more battery, Nouveau or Nvidia driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery

On a hybrid laptop with on-board Intel graphics and a dedicated Nvidia graphics chip, which setup will use less battery power?

1. Nouveau opensource driver:

   - I believe this *only* uses the onboard Intel chip; correct me if I am wrong?
2. Nvidia proprietary driver with *PRIME Profile* set to *Intel*:

   - Is this equivalent to option 1 from a power usage perspective?
3. Nvidia proprietary driver with *PRIME Profile* set to *NVIDIA*:

   - Since you get *PowerMizer* with this option, the graphics clock automatically throttles down as needed.  Therefore, it may actually be a viable option from a battery usage perspective?
   - Which *Preferred Mode* is better, *Adaptive* or *Auto*?
   - (I think it's safe to assume *Prefer Maximum Performance* will not be conducive to battery savings, so let's not consider this as a viable setting for this question).

(Note: this is for Ubuntu 17.10, using Xorg, not Wayland).

Choices for Option 1...
[image: Software & Updates]

Choices for Option 2...
[image: Nvidia Prime Profiles]

Choices for Option 3...
[image: Nvidia PowerMizer]

Comment: Seems like you should give each one a test, and then tell us....